# NotAuthorizedException - incorrect username or password when trying to change user password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to change the password of a user. My user sends the old and new password from the client-side as well as their access token. Do I require more config on the back end side?
This is my back-end code:

```
const {
    CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
    ChangePasswordCommand,
} = require('@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider')

const cognitoConfig = {}

if (process.env.IS_OFFLINE) {
    cognitoConfig.credentials = {
        accessKeyId: 'xxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxx',
    }
}

const cognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(cognitoConfig)

const changePassword = async (event, context) => {
    console.log(event)
    const { body, headers } = event
    const { oldPassword, newPassword } = JSON.parse(body)

    const command = new ChangePasswordCommand({
        PreviousPassword: oldPassword,
        ProposedPassword: newPassword,
        AccessToken: headers.authorization,
    })
    const response = await cognitoClient.send(command)
    return response
}
```